# CSV parsing nullpointerexception

Tags: java, csv, nullpointerexception

I am taking in CSV files from Nasdaq and am using Apache Commons CSV to parse it. For some reason I am getting a NullPointerException and I can't seem to figure out why.

These are my lines where I create the reader and parser

```
data = new URL("http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?industry=Health%20Care&render=download");
Reader dataReader= new InputStreamReader(new BOMInputStream(data.openStream()), "UTF-8");
CSVParser dataParse= new CSVParser(dataReader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader());
```

I am then adding to an ArrayList to store the values:

```
for (final CSVRecord record : dataParse) {
    myArrayList.add(new MyClass(record.get("Symbol"),         
    record.get("Industry")));
}
```

It seems to me like the CSV file is fine, so not sure why this would be happening.
Thanks

Comment: Add the error stacktrace.

Comment: try breaking the three lines of code into their own (separate) lines and see where the NPE is being thrown. Without a full stack trace is impossible to tell from here.  Hint: use a debugger for faster results

Comment: The first three lines I included are where the error is occurring

Comment: sure, but which one?  each line has 3 or 4 potential sources of the NPE.  If  you break it into separate lines, it's easier to tell which one is the source.  and what about that stacktrace?